# javax.mail throws IndexOutOfBoundsException when index do exists

Tags: scala, jakarta-mail

package using:

com.sun.mail:javax.mail:1.5.6 from maven

I wrote a scala program where I use `javax.mail` to deal with emails. In the first part I get some mail id by `message.getMessageNumber` and later when I tried to retrieve the mail by these id `IndexOutOfBoundsException` happened. Mail server has nothing changed during the process.

Here is the code I get the id of messages.

```
val Final = new AndTerm(Subject,Size)
//val FinalTerm = new AndTerm(From)
val messages = inbox.search(Final).map{
  message=>
    val date = trim(message.getSubject)
    (date,message.getMessageNumber)
}.filter(_._1.isDefined).map(_._2)
inbox.close(true)
store.close
```

And here is the code Exception throwed.

```
//newed another store and Folder with the same name
val ContentType = messages.map(id=>inbox.getMessage(id).getContentType())
inbox.close(true)
store.close
```

The Exception Message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: 416 > 64
at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPFolder.checkRange(IMAPFolder.java:513)
at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPFolder.getMessage(IMAPFolder.java:1770)
at EmailReader.MessageByNumber(EmailReader.scala:67)
at Main$$anonfun$main$1.apply(Main.scala:43)
at Main$$anonfun$main$1.apply(Main.scala:41)
at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:186)
at Main$.main(Main.scala:40)
at Main.main(Main.scala)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
```

The `416 > 64` gives me a hint that maybe there is some server-side limitation, is that true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're closing the Folder after fetching the Message objects.  Message numbers (and Message objects) are only valid while the folder is open.

Comment: more info about accepting this answer: server-side closed my connection due to their rules to ban some 'strange action', contacted admin solved this

Answer (score 0):

I believe the numbers represent that you passed an ID of 416 whereas the count of the collection is 64. It appears that getMessage(id) may be attempting to look for a number to retrieve that message from the array; such as getMessage(0) would be the first in the collection. Instead, it appears the code is passing the Message ID which is not directly translatable to the number in the collection.